# Dynamically resize element with window size jquery

Tags: jquery, resize

I've looked at many questions regarding this subject and can not seem to find out what is wrong with my code. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
$(window).resize(function(){
   var newwidth = $(window).innerWidth();
   var newheight = $(window).innerHeight();      
   $("#element").height(newheight).width(newwidth);
       });
```

I'm trying to resize #element to the same height and width as the window if the window is resized.

Comment: See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aBHRp/1/

Comment: Help me, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33360273/window-disptachevent-resizing-issue

Answer (score 13, accepted):

About `.innerWidth()`, from [docs](http://api.jquery.com/innerWidth/):

> This method is not applicable to window and document objects; for
>   these, use .width() instead.

There is same [note](http://api.jquery.com/innerHeight/) for `.innerHeight()` also.

So you need to use `.width()` and `.height()`:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var newwidth = $(window).width();
    var newheight = $(window).height();      
    $("#element").height(newheight).width(newwidth);
});
```

Comment: thanks for the response. It's interesting because if I alert(newwidth) i do get the correct width.

Comment: @Tyrsius Maybe there is a cross-browser compatibility problem.

Comment: @Engineer that's possible. I am using Chrome.

Comment: @MinaGabriel If `inner(Width|Height)` works on Chrome, it does not mean,it will work on all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
   var newwidth = $(window).width();
   var newheight = $(window).height();      
   $("#element").css({"height": newheight, "width": newwidth });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In plain Javascript you can do this:

```
    var viewportwidth;
    var viewportheight;

    // the more standards compliant browsers (mozilla/netscape/opera/IE7) use window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight

    if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined')
    {
        viewportwidth = window.innerWidth,
        viewportheight = window.innerHeight
    }

    // IE6 in standards compliant mode (i.e. with a valid doctype as the first line in the document)

    else if (typeof document.documentElement != 'undefined'
     && typeof document.documentElement.clientWidth !=
     'undefined' && document.documentElement.clientWidth != 0)
    {
         viewportwidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth,
         viewportheight = document.documentElement.clientHeight
    }

    // older versions of IE

    else
    {
         viewportwidth = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth,
         viewportheight = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight
    }
    var mydiv = document.getElementById("element");
    mydiv.style.height=viewportheight'px';
    mydiv.style.width=viewportwidth+'px';
```

Answer (score 1):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/minagabriel/PZz9h/)

```
 $(window).resize(function(){
var newwidth = $(window).width();
var newheight = $(window).height();      
$("#element").height(newheight).width(newwidth);
  });​
```

both works for me

[update](http://jsfiddle.net/minagabriel/PZz9h/1/)

```
 $(window).resize(function(){
var newwidth = $(window).innerWidth();
var newheight = $(window).innerHeight();      
$("#element").height(newheight).width(newwidth);
  });​
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always just use CSS:

```css
#element {width:100%; height:100%; position:fixed; }
```

Comment: downvote? this does the same thing the Op has in their code, except without the jQuery.