# window. disptachevent resizing issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, resize

On window `resize()` triggering, it has to take the "`#snapContainer`" **div** (I mean `background-css` properties)

My jquery code is ,

```
$('#snapContainer').css({"background-size": "95%",
"min-height": "100%",
"position": "relative",
"left": "2%",
"margin-bottom": "15%",
"display": "inline-block"});
$('.'+snapCloseClass).show();
//window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
$(window).resize(function() {
  $('#snapContainer').css({"background-size": "95%",
  "min-height": "100%",
  "position": "relative",
  "left": "2%",
  "margin-bottom": "15%",
  "display": "inline-block"});
});
```

Comment: Can you update what issue you are facing?

Comment: $(window).resize(function(), should resize as per div values. Here in this context div= #snapContainer values.

But now, window is changing as per device width * height values.